# AngularJS checkboxes dont remain checked if they are filtered away then returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a list with checkboxes that can be filtered using a textbox as a search field

```
<input type="search" id="valSearch" value="" placeholder="Please type name..." class="search-input" ng-model="query">  
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list__item list__item--tappable" ng-repeat="name in classList | filter:query">  
         <label class="checkbox checkbox--list-item">  
             <input type="checkbox" class="chkProperty" value="{{id.childName}}">  
                {{id.childName}}  
        </label>  
     </li>  
</ul>
```

The problem I am having is if a checkbox is selected and then a search is made, once the search field is cleared and the entire list is shown, the checkboxes that were selected do not remain checked when they return if they were hidden during the search. I've tried using jquery to check the boxes when they return as follows

```
$('#valSearch').on('keypress', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {                    
            $.each($(".chkProperty"), function (i, e) {
                if (nameList[i] == e.value) { //nameList is an array that contains all the selected items
                    $(this).attr("checked", true);
                }
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? you're mixing angular and jQuery where it seems you shouldn't be.

Comment: How is the filtering performed?

Comment: When I select a checkbox and then type in the search field so the box I selected is no longer visible I want it to remain checked when the filter is removed and that checkbox is showing again. I have "filter:query in the ng-repeat", query is the textbox that you type what you want to filter by

Comment: Please create a plunker or jsFiddle demonstrating the problem, otherwise getting debugging help may be difficult

Comment: need to use `ng-model` to bind inputs to your data. And don't manipulate them with jQuery if you don't want mass confusion in your app

Comment: Sounds rather like the checkbox elements are replaced, not hidden/shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat` will remove the DOM and all references to it when an item is not returned from the filter. Thus, if the item was checked, it is no longer checked when it gets re-inserted into the DOM because it's a brand new DOM (not the old DOM).

To solve this issue, you need to have the data (nameList) also keep the [state of the item](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/04/24/modeling-data-and-state-in-your-angularjs-application/) (checked/unchecked). That way each input can see if it's checked inside the `ng-repeat`. To do this, just have the input use an `ng-model`.

[plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/SNzKEfmmgPL35S3otpBt?p=preview)

Comment: @TejinderSingh since the state of the checkbox is stored in the controller `classList` array, you can remove the `checked` property or set it to false for each item.

Comment: Actually , I have a modal popup having list of dynamically bound checkboxes, with search option. it works fine when I search anything and removes it. but at some point it gets failed.